# How to show a webview (with all interaction) in secondary display, like apple Tv

Tags: ios, webview, swift3, external, display

I have a viewcontroller which has a webview attached to it. I wan't to mirror it to external screen connected to ipad. I am able to create new window and show images and all, but here i want the exact mirroring of UIWebview (all taps, links, textfield input in web page, video) on secondary display.

```
    func initiateTheExternalDisplay() {

    guard UIScreen.screens.count > 1 else {
        return
    }
    let externalScreen = UIScreen.screens[1]
    let externalWindow = UIWindow(frame: externalScreen.bounds)
    self.externalSecondaryWindow = externalWindow

    let roortVc = ExternalPresentationViewController() // this contains view to be shown
    self.externalPresentationViewController = rootVc
    externalWindow.rootViewController = rootVc
    externalWindow.screen = externalScreen

    externalWindow.isHidden = false
    externalWindow.makeKeyAndVisible()
}
```

This is how i am instantiating the secondary display and is working fine. Suppose same class is showing the webview, can anyone suggest what info should i pass from here (or alternate way) to achieve mirroring.

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't find any way to do so, so I used a work around. I taking screenshots of the web view controller and updating the secondary view at around 20fps, so it lags a bit but at least able to see the same interaction in almost rela time.